# Exporting MatrixForm Expression as Raster Image With Fixed Size

Tags: export, image, rasterize

I have an array defined as such:

```
x0 = 6;
xmin = 7;
xmax = 20;
Ω = ConstantArray[0, {xmax, xmax}];

Do[
 Do[
  If[i == j + 1, Ω[[i, j]] += 1];
  If[i == j, Ω[[i, j]] -= 1 - γ];
  If[i == j && j >= x0 + xmin, Ω[[i, j]] -= β];
  If[i >= x0 && i <= j - xmin && 
    j >= x0 + xmin, Ω[[i, 
     j]] += β/(j - xmin - x0 + 1)];
  If[i >= xmin && i <= j - x0 && 
    j >= x0 + xmin, Ω[[i, 
     j]] += β/(j - xmin - x0 + 1)]
  , {j, 1, xmax}]
 , {i, 1, xmax}]
```

Which I then want to join to a string using an operation like row:

```
print = Row[{"Ω=" , MatrixForm[Ω]}];
```

How can I export this as a jpg of a fixed size and/or fixed DPI?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I get everything correctly, but you can Rasterize the MatrixForm of your matrix and you also can specify the imageSize:

```
img = Rasterize[MatrixForm[\[CapitalOmega]], ImageSize -> {1920, 600}];

Export["D:/yourPath/filename.jpg", img]
```